# Is it possible to delay the loading of a class, that might be loaded dynamically later?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm wondering, and I have tried a myriad of convoluted search terms to determine if there was a way to delay the loading of a class in Java. What I mean is, the classes can be found on the class/build path, but I don't want them loaded at launch time. This results in the wrong class loader being used.

Can I, selectively or not, delay or prevent the default class loader from loading certain classes/JARs?

*Example* (with the 3rd party jar on the build path):

```
// boilerplate main
JarWrapper apiJar = SpecialJarLoader("api.jar"); // SpecialJarLoader is a proprietary class loader
Class apiClass = apiJar.loadClass("org.company.comm.AConnection"); // runtime failure here due to the class already being loaded
```

If I remove the Jar from the build path, apiClass.getClassLoader() is the proprietary loader as expected. The issue is that I am not free to use "org.company.comm.AConnection" or any other classes in the Jar (including the IDE's autocomplete), because it's not actually on the build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that is to write your CUSTOM JAVA loader using JNI(that is, in C)

This way, you can SELECTIVELY load a class.

Comment: Is there a "simple" example of this? Or should I just dig into JNI?

Answer (score 5):

Classes are loaded only when they are first used. Thus your class will not be loaded at launch time but rather at the first time something from this class (including a static method, type declaration, etc.) is needed. Thus, the default behavior is that loading as delayed as long as possible.

If you want to control the loading time you can load the class explicitly via ClassLoaer.loadClass(). If your class is wrapped with some interface, you can have the code access only on the interface (thus ensuring the class is not loaded by some chain of dependencies) and then load it (ClassLoader.loadclass()) & instantiate it when you actually need an instance of this class.

Comment: I believe you are correct, and I'm not asking you to tell me what the code is doing but I have this experience where if I add the JAR to the build path, sun's loader is used for the class before the 3rd party class loader utility can be called. If I remove the JAR from the build path, the appropriate class loader (3rd party) can be called and used.

Comment: Can you then make your question more concrete? perhaps a short code sample that surfaces the problem?

Comment: I'd be happy to oblige, but I honestly have no idea how to better explain my "issue". I will characterise it as my issue, since it's obviously a deficiency in my Java knowledge. I can add a simple code sample, however I didn't originally think it would add much.

Comment: @christopher If you preload a class with the desired class loader manually, Java won't try to reload it with the system class loader at a later time, it will use the one you preloaded. Does this sound like what you want to do?

Comment: @SamuelAudet yes this sounds exactly like what I want to do. How do I "preload" the class, while still having it available to use in the IDE (autocomplete, etc.)

Comment: @christopher Try to call your `loadClass()` code early in the `main()` method for example... The `Class` object won't get garbage collected until the `ClassLoader` is.

Comment: I've done exactly this... and it still results in the sun loader being used *before* the statement. If I remove the .jar from my build/class path, it loads properly -- but then I don't have access to the class in the IDE.